# How to write a function that gets the sum of 2 functions?

Tags: ocaml

I have to write a code that creates a function let's say "f" that calculates the sum of 2 functions let's say "h" and "g". I wrote it like this:

```
let h x = x + 2;;
let g x = x + 4;;
let f h x g x = h x + g x;;
```

But when I type let's say `f h 2 g 4;;`it shows me 14 which is wrong cause it should show me 12. Why?

Also can I make it somehow that I can choose which functions to sum when I run the code or I need to set the functions before every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are shadowing the `x` parameter in `f`, so `f h 2 g 4` will evaluate to `h 4 + g 4`. All you need to do is name one of the parameters something else, like `y`:

```
let f h x g y = h x + g y;;
```

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about "the sum of two functions" in a mathematical sense, then we should have a function takes two parameters `g` and `h` which are both functions, and returns a result which is also a function (usually denoted by `g+h`, and which is such that `(g+h)(x) = g(x) + h(x)`).

So, the goal is to write a function `sum` like that:

```
let sum g h =
    ...
```

which returns a function that takes an argument `x` and returns `f(x) + g(x)`.

One could do it this way:

```
let sum g h =
    fun x -> (g x) + (h x)
```

You can check the type of `sum`:

```
val sum : ('a -> int) -> ('a -> int) -> 'a -> int = <fun>
```

which means:

- it takes a first argument of type `('a -> int)` (which is a function that takes one argument and returns an integer: the one we called g),
- it takes a second argument also of type  `('a -> int)` (the one we called h),
- it abouts a function also of type `'a -> int`, which is what we want (since `g+h` is indeed a function that takes an argument and returns an integer.

In most programming languages, you'd be forced to have that kind of function definition. In OCaml, thanks to [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and some black magic, you're allowed to say "But wait, you decided to group the last `'a -> int` and call that the return type of `sum`, but could it instead be that the `'a` is a third argument of `sum` and that its return type is just `int`"? And that would be the same as saying that we can see `sum` "functor" as a function taking `g` and `h` as its arguments and returning a new function which, when called on `x`, will return `g(x)+h(x)`, but we can equivalently see it as a function taking three arguments `g`, `h` and `x` and returning `g(x)+h(x)`. These two visions are equivalent in OCaml. So we can make our code simpler and just write:

```
let sum g h x = (g x) + (h x)
```

You can verify that the type of that is still

```
val sum : ('a -> int) -> ('a -> int) -> 'a -> int = <fun>
```

as expected.

---

From there you can have syntactic fun and define your own sum operator for functions, like `++` for instance:

```
let (++) g h x = (g x) + (h x)
```

And then use it after defining `g` and `h`:

```
let g = ( ( + ) 5 )
and h = ( ( * ) 2 )
in
(g ++ h) 3
```

which will return `(g+h)(3) = g(3) + h(3) = (5+3) + (2*3) = 14`.